# Proper notation in persistence.xml to change encoding to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, jpa, jdbc, utf-8, persistence.xml

Which of this notation is proper in `persistence.xml` file for web application in TomEE server with OpenJPA module to connect with MySQL database and set UTF-8 encoding?

1. `<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>`
   (**yes** and **UTF-8**)
2. `<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"/>`
   (**true** and **utf8**)
3. `<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci/>`

For what is property `characterSetResults=utf8`? Should I use it to change encoding or not?

Comment: All the properties are listed and described in the documentation (surprisingly): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: thanks, but at `characterEncoding` property there isn't information about proper value: `utf8` or `UTF-8`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html